# How do the words "not a single-group group function" express what they aim to express

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I understand that, when one uses both an aggregate function and an individual column not mentioned in GROUP BY, the "not a single-group group function" error message results. However, I still cannot understand the cryptic words "single-group group function". How do these words express what they aim to express?

Comment: It is Oracle-speak for "aggregation function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you omit a group key in a `group by` query, like this:

```
select job_id, department_id, max(salary) from employees
group by job_id;
```

it will indicate the offending expression (in this example `department_id`) with the error
`ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

but what should it say when you omit the `group by` clause as well? It's valid not to have one, e.g.

```
select max(salary) from employees;
```

but what about

```
select department_id, max(salary) from employees;
```

It can't say "not a GROUP BY expression", because there's no `group by`. It has to say either that it's missing a `group by` (which would be a bit of a guess, because you might not have wanted one), or else that it's a malformed attempt at a query like `select max(salary) from employees` that goes wrong at the word `department_id`, because it is not an aggregate function. So it highlights `department_id` and reports that it is not what it was expecting, which would have been a group function appropriate for a single-group query.

The message *"not a single-group group function"* may seem a bit clumsy, but it's hard to come up with anything clearer to express this error condition.

I wondered what Oracle uses in other languages, and I got:

```
ORA-00937: la fonction de groupe ne porte pas sur un groupe simple
```

*"the group function does not relate to a single group"*

```
ORA-00937: keine Gruppenfunktion fⁿr Einzelgruppe
```

*"no group function for individual groups"*

and

```
ORA-00937: tΣmΣ ei ole yhden ryhmΣn koostefunktio
```

*"ORA-00937: This is not a single group aggregation function"*

I think the last one (Finnish) is the clearest, because it uses "aggregation function" rather than repeating the word "group", but it is a tricky concept to express in a one-line error message.

Comment: Do you mean that the word "single" in "single group" refers to the fact that there is only one group because of the absence of `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 2):

The aggregate functions are sort of group functions. They can be executed against a group of values only - this is why "group function"

That kind of functions can be applied to the one (single) group of values only, like "max number of employees working in [ONE] department". This is what makes that functions to "single-group"

Comment: So, suppose I don't use a GROUP BY clause. This makes the whole table a single group. Now, if I specify an individual column in addition to the aggregate function, how does this make the function non-single-group?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It doesn't make the function non-single-group. By saying "not a single...." database points out to the individual column you've just added and means "Hey! This column is not a single-group function"